# How can I subscribe to the OverScrolled event, fired from a Xamarin.Android renderer, in a custom ListView control in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a custom NoBounceListView control in my Xamarin.Forms application that inherits from the base ListView class. The code for this class is as follows:

```
namespace MyApp.Controls
{
    public class NoBounceListView : ListView
    {
        public NoBounceListView()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a renderer class called NoBounceListViewRenderer for this control that prevents the list view from bouncing when the user scrolls to the top of the list by handling the OnOverScrolled event and raising the OverScrolled event. The code for this class is as follows:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NoBounceListView), typeof(NoBounceListViewRenderer))]

namespace MyApp.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class NoBounceListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer, INoBounceListViewRenderer
    {
        public event EventHandler OverScrolled;

        public NoBounceListViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, bool clampedX, bool clampedY)
        {
            base.OnOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);

            if (clampedY)
            {
                OverScrolled?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to subscribe to the OverScrolled event in my NoBounceListView class in MyApp to take some specific action when the list view is over-scrolled. However, since the OverScrolled event is defined in the renderer class, I am not sure how to access it in my NoBounceListView class.

Can someone please suggest how I can get the OverScrolled event in my NoBounceListView class so that I can take the necessary action when the list view is over-scrolled? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your renderer can access your View class. Instead of having view hook an event in renderer, have renderer call a method you declare in your View.